# Create a custom Drupal image using Dockerfile for local testing

Tags: docker, image, drupal, dockerfile, dockerhub

I'm trying to create a custom Drupal image for local testing, but I don't know what exactly to add in the Dockerfile's `workdir`, `cmd`, `run` and so on.

I've been searching but there is no help from the internet about custom Drupal images. Even tags Dockerfile for Drupal are useless and provide no help.

Answer (score 1):

You could just copy what is in one of the [official drupal docker images](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal) and edit it as needed.
For your local dev environment, [Lando](https://docs.lando.dev/) is a popular option that makes things a little easier than setting up your own docker containers.